# JUnit test report testsuite's timestamp is epoch

Tags: junit, gradle

In my test execution, some junit classes report that their timestamp is 1970. Why might this happen?

```
<testsuite name="my.BlahTest" tests="2" failures="0" errors="0" 
    timestamp="1970-01-01T00:00:00" hostname="DEV-DT22" time="1.36139893834E9">
```

This does not happen to the same classes each test run. Nor does it ever happen to all of the classes. I'm using the java plugin for gradle to execute the JUnit tests and have never *noticed* this issue when using JUnit via Ant.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug. Please report it at http://forums.gradle.org and include as many details as you can (test task configuration, ways to reproduce, Gradle version, etc.).